# Is there any method/algorithm to estimate the magnitude of non-stationarity in a signal?

Tags: statistics, non-linear, stationary

e.g. the [global Lyapunov exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_exponent) can give sense of the level of chaos in the signal. Is there any reliable numerical technique to estimate "how" non-stationary (or how predictable) a signal is?
Also, is the [Hurst exponent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurst_exponent) appropriate for this purpose? The time signals I'm interested in come from natural processes like fluid flow. I want to study signals based on how non-stationary they are.

Comment: I was thinking on a "dynamic index" measure, with 1 a totally dynamical system and 0 a static relationship, or a "periodicity index" measure, with 1 if the signal is periodic or convergent and 0 if is chaotic. For the first case, one would expect the number of estimated states could serve (if such kind of object could be defined). Hence a single index would not be rightly possible?. Maybe the same object for checking chaos-ity indicates how much periodic is the signal. In fact chaos is the contrary of periodic and/of convergent.

Comment: I guess if you may assume stationary for short time then evolution of eigenvlaues over time would reflect nonstationarity.

Comment: For such you need to define order. Which is actually a measure of how dynamic a system is. Not how periodic / chaotic. You should then check the degeneracy of these eigenvalues. If and only if, you have very well identified your system. :)

Comment: yeah, I was thinking along the lines of measuring WSSity by looking how well the Wiener-Khinchin theorem applies e.g. by comparing short-windowed FTs, which is actually just a special case of your eigenvalue considerations.

Comment: The signals come from flow turbulence, so I can't identify the system too well. What do you folks think about using the Hurst exponent?